# how to get a value from a returned JSON array

Tags: php, json

If i have:

```
print_r($request->getRequestVars());
```

that prints out:

```
Array ( [n] => Coors [s] => 3 )
```

how would i print out coors?

```
echo $request->getRequestVars()->n;
```

is not working, and i've tried several other things. I know this is super basic but it's frustrating me

Comment: `getRequestVars()` returns an array, not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php

$var = $request->getRequestVars();
echo $var['n'];

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the method `$request->getRequestVars();` acutally returns an array.
So, you would have to do something along the lines of:

```
$foo = $request->getRequestVars();
echo $foo['n'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `$request->getRequestVars()` returns array not object. `PHP 5.4` has [Function Array Dereferencing](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing) if that is what you are running then you can have:

```
echo $request->getRequestVars()['n'];
```

else

```
$v = $request->getRequestVars();
echo $v['n'];
```